# Why no 'b' in numeric etc

Tags: etymology, orthography

"Number" vs. "Numeric"

Also "Enumerate" etc.

If I were to guess, I might go for it relating to "Numeral", but I don't see why it should derive from the less common word, nor why Numeral has no b itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact the odd-one-out is the word *number*.  The words enumerate and numeral come more directly from Latin whereas 'number' comes to us via  French and only indirectly from Latin.

In cases like this I recommend an etymology dictionary such as [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php).

[origin of number](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=number&allowed_in_frame=0)  "from Anglo-French noumbre, Old French nombre"

[origin of numeral](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=numeral&searchmode=none) "from Middle French numéral (late 15c.), from Late Latin numeralis "of or belonging to a number," from Latin numerus "a number"

EDIT

I suppose you could now ask why there were two spellings in French!  I guess that is a question for a French etymology dictionary and so not really on-topic here. Let's see if anyone else can answer that part. Alternatively you could ask on the [French site](https://french.stackexchange.com/). They accept questions written in English and one of the members might have just the right dictionary.

Comment: French liked to put an epenthetic 'b' between 'm' and 'r'. Compare (Latin→French→English) *camera→chambre→chamber* and *flammare→flamber→flambé*. For *numéral* (which apparently was original the adjective corresponding to *nombre*), there's a vowel between the 'm' and the 'r', so you don't need to add a 'b', but in *nombre* that vowel disappeared.

Comment: @PeterShor Not just French; it's a common trait in the Romance languages (and elsewhere) that /mr ml/ become /mbr mbl/ while /nr nl/ becomes /ndr ndl/; Greek does both as well (ανήρ _anēr_, gen. ανδρός _andrós_, and _ambrosia_ is really the drink of the immortal, from _a-_ (‘un-’) + _mr(o)ti-_ (‘dead’, like _mortus_ in Latin). _Flambé_ is different, though: _flamber_ is derived from _flambe_, which is dissimilated from _flamble_, from Latin _flammula_ ‘little flame’, and which merged with _flamme_ in Old French. There was never a sequence /mr/ in that word, though.

Comment: @PeterShor (Compare also Spanish _hombre_ ‘man’ < _homre_ < _homne_ < Latin _hominem_, accusative of _homō_ ‘person’.)

Comment: Also compare 'fambly', a [now-defunct?] dialectal form of English 'family'.